# How to get the list item that is opened and showing another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a list view in activity A  . When the list item has clicked it opens another activityB. The activity B has a button which when clicked shows the list item which the activity B originated from when clicked as a toast message. It's this possible. 
Please help me

**this us the code I tried in activity B**

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            List< MyList> mlist = null;

            MyList codes = (MyList) getItem(position);
        }

            private Object getItem(int position)
            {
                return mlist.get(position);
            }
    });
```

I am getting a error at position saying unknown variable position

**activity a on them click listener**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int position, long p4)
{
    Codelist codes = (CodeList) get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);


                intent.putExtra("selected item" , codes);
                 startActivity(intent);

}
```

**newly tried code**

```
Button favbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewButton);
    favbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            List <CodeList> codelist = null;
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            CodeList codes = extras.getParcelable("selected item");
            if(checkArchivedItem(codes)){

                        archvPrefrnces.removeArchive(SingleItemView.this, codes);
                    }else{

                        archvPrefrnces.addArchive(SingleItemView.this, codes);


                        Toast.makeText(SingleItemView.this, getString(R.string.archive_added), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


        }
        private boolean checkArchivedItem(CodeList checkCodes) {
                    boolean check = false;
                    List<CodeList> archives = archvPrefrnces.getArchives(getApplicationContext());
                    if (archives != null) {
                        for (CodeList codes : archives) {
                            if (codes.equals(checkCodes)) {
                                check = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return check;
                }       



    });
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Show some details of the item you just clicked inside activity B or just close activity B in order to return inside activity A (with the all list) ?

Comment: @Rob show details about which item was clicked

Comment: Ok, as @Bhawna Raheja explained, you can use "parcelable" for your model, that means put your object inside an intent (to go from A to B) and then get the data you need in B. Hope it'll work :)

Comment: @Rob Yeah tank you for looking into my question. I am trying that out

Comment: @Rob did it Added this as you said intent.putExtra("selected item" , mlist.get(position)); but getting an error saying there is no applicable method

Comment: If you want to use the parcelable method, you need to change your code a little bit, especially in your model class "MyList". 
In my opinion, maybe you should use @Avinash Joshi method if you only need to get a few data inside activity B (like String or int), it will be easier and quicker for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make your model Parcelable that you want to send. Then in your activity A on selection of a item write:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
   intent.putExtra("SELECTED_ITEM", selectedItemObject);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your activity B, code for button click listener should be like:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.singleitemviewButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Item item extras.getParcelable("SELECTED_ITEM"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Added this as you said intent.putExtra("selected item" , mlist.get(position)); but getting an error saying there is no applicable method

Comment: Can you post your code here and where you have written this code?

Comment: I have written it in the activity A on item click listener

Comment: Have you make your model Parcelable or Serializable?

Comment: You must have a class named MyList in your app. Go into this class and make it Serializable like this :
MyList implements Serializable { //your code} And then change code in activity B to MyList item =  extras.getSerializable("SELECTED_ITEM");

Comment: I am try it and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101178/discussion-between-bhawna-raheja-and-user5524159).

Answer (score 0):

when you start the new activity on the item click you can send the position or other details that you want to show in your toast in the intent you pass to the activity as follows

```
intent.putExtra("details 1", "position or some thing");
intent.putExtra("details 2", "something");
intent.putExtra("details", "something");
startActivity(intent);
```

now in the activity you can get by doing so

```
String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("details 1");
Stirng s2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("details 2");
```

Comment: You said position or something, but how to get the position

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want to show from your list

Comment: not show w when the button is clicked I want the item which opens the activity contacting button to be added to favorites activity via shared preferences

Comment: I ha have already created the sharedpreference and implementing the process of adding to favorites via onitemlongclicllstener in activity A. But I want to do the same via button click in activity B. Hope you understand. Please help me

Comment: wherever you are getting your list it you must have a unique id for that particular item I assume now when you click the item you pass the detalis like the unique Id or what ever as shown in the answer. Now in activity B you get the intent and the extras as shown onclick of the button and pass them to the prefrence so when you create a fravoriets list check the prefrences for the id and create a list containing those only or hide the others

Comment: I have posted again what I tried please have a look

Comment: can you post the code that does that so i can help you make it work with the button

Comment: posted it have alook

Comment: the app is crashing giving a nullpointerexception on checkcodesline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101188/discussion-between-avinash-joshi-and-user5524159).